# Why can SQL Server 2012 not add an included column to an existing non clustered index

Tags: sql-server, database, indexing

I don't understand why it is not as simple as

```
alter index whatever add included (columnName)
```

What would prevent this from being a simple operation to SQL Server that would add the column to the index and populate the value in the pages from the table?

This would not affect the ordering at all of the index, just trying to optimize a select statement. I was hoping that I can have less down time than the 8 hours it would currently take to drop and rebuild a set of indexes but I was sadly disappointed.

Comment: Can't you just specify `with (Online = On)`?  Most indexes can be altered and stay online.

Comment: Because of the amount of page splits likely to ensue adding this column to every row on all leaf pages recreating the index from scratch will be quicker anyway. You could probably use `drop_existing` to avoid the need to sort the data again.

Comment: Actually the sort will still be needed regardless because of course the existing index doesn't cover that column and it won't do 100% lookups back to the base table to get it.

Comment: Why did you comment an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the included column is in the index page, so at the moment you have something like:

Page
  Row 1: Key 1, Key 2, Inc 1 Row 2: Key 1, Key 2, Inc 1, Row 3: Key 1, Key 2, Inc 1 ...

If row 1 starts at byte 0, row 2 is at byte x, etc

To add a new included column you would need to take each page, break it into rows add the column and then re-write it, possibly on either just 1 page or more than 1 pages, including the metadata from the previous pages that points to it - effectively you are having to completly re-write the index so why not just rebuild it.

It is cheaper for SQL Server to build a new index than insert little pieces of data here and there.

EDIT: Also you would obviously get index fragmentation so you would need to then rebuild it

Comment: That makes sense. I wasn't thinking deeply enough into what exactly an index was.